# syncfusion chart does not display data

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios

I added SFchart, it had no errors and it compiles. It shows an empty chartview.
I'm using MVVMcross in Xamarin.IOS

The data I requested is there, it contains about 200 rows, the data is requested from my api with the method `override void viewAppearing`.

My view in viewdidload:

```
 //Initialize the Chart with required frame. This frame can be any rectangle, which bounds inside the view.
        SFChart chart = new SFChart();
        chart.Frame = this.headerView.Frame;

        //Adding Primary Axis for the Chart.
        SFCategoryAxis primaryAxis = new SFCategoryAxis();
        chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

        //Adding Secondary Axis for the Chart.
        SFNumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new SFNumericalAxis();
        chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;
        chart.Series.Add(new SFColumnSeries()
        {

            ItemsSource = (this.ViewModel as UserCoinViewModel).CoinHistory,

            XBindingPath = "price_btc",

            YBindingPath = "timestamp"

        });


        this.View.AddSubview(chart);
```

viewmodel:

```
private List<CoinHistoryModel> _CoinHistory;

    public List<CoinHistoryModel> CoinHistory
    {
        get
        {
            return _CoinHistory;
        }
        set
        {
            _CoinHistory = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CoinHistory);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using MVVMcross, you should use `bind` method to set your `Series`'s `ItemsSource`. You just set the `ItemsSource` to the viewModel instance's property, when the value changed it will not notify the View. So it seems to show an empty chart.

Modify your code to bind like:

```
SFColumnSeries series = new SFColumnSeries()
{
    XBindingPath = "price_btc",

    YBindingPath = "timestamp"
};
chart.Series.Add(series);

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<YourView, UserCoinViewModel>();
...
        set.Bind(series).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.CoinHistory);
...
set.Apply();
```

Then in your ViewModel, create a command like:

```
private MvxCommand loadDataCommand;
public ICommand LoadDataCommand
{
    get
    {
        return loadDataCommand ?? (loadDataCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteloadDataCommand));
    }
}
private void ExecuteloadDataCommand()
{
    CoinHistory = new List<CoinHistoryModel>()
    {
        new CoinHistoryModel{ price_btc = "First", timestamp = 10 },
        new CoinHistoryModel{ price_btc = "Second", timestamp = 20 },
        new CoinHistoryModel{ price_btc = "Third", timestamp = 30 }
    };
    // Change it to your data request here
}
```

At last trigger this command in your `ViewWillAppear()` event:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    (ViewModel as UserCoinViewModel).LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);
    // You can also bind a button to this command to trigger it manually.
}
```

Comment: on you're last part i get an error that ViewModel does not exist in the current context? is this a value i should change? edit: also i can't use the bool animated part

Comment: also get an error that the binding fails? only diffirence is that i use 'MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet' the other binding are successfull

Comment: You used `this.ViewModel as UserCoinViewModel`, so I guess this is your viewmodel. Does it inherit from `MvxViewModel`? And does your view inherit from `MvxViewController`?

Comment: yes 'userCoinViewModel' is indeed the viewmodel. and yes they both inherit from mvxViewModel and mvxViewController

Comment: `ViewModel` is what you did in your `ViewDidLoad()`: `(this.ViewModel as UserCoinViewModel).CoinHistory`. You can use this property in that event, why you can't use it in the `ViewWillAppear()` event?

Comment: viewdidload is in the view file, the 'override void viewAppearing' is in the viewmodel file

Comment: What I mean is: in your ViewModel file create a command as i said above. Then trigger it in the View file like in the ViewWillAppear() event.

Comment: The `ViewWillAppear()` is also the lifecycle of a ViewController as `ViewDidLoad()`. You can override it in the View file.

Comment: it executes the command, but the binding still fails ' Failed to create target binding for binding  for CoinHistory'

Comment: probably should mention that i want this graph in a view that i set on a tableview

Comment: Lu, your binding is wrong. it should be "            set.Bind(series).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.CoinHistory);
"

Comment: Both this way and the property name method can be worked on my side.

Comment: Hi @AchielVolckaert, I made a simple sample about these two methods working well. You can refer to it [here](https://github.com/landl0526/SFChartUsingMVVMCrossDemo).