# sfChart reset data for graph

Tags: xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I have a graph in a 'detail' view. this is accessed when an item is chosen in a tableview. the first graph is correct, but when I pick another item in the table, it still shows the first graph. I enabled `ListenPropertyChange = true` and `raispropertychanged` it twice.

view(viewdidload):

```
SFChart chart = new SFChart();
        chart.Frame = this.headerview.Frame;

        //Adding Primary Axis for the Chart.
        SFCategoryAxis primaryAxis = new SFCategoryAxis();
        chart.PrimaryAxis = primaryAxis;

        //Adding Secondary Axis for the Chart.
        SFNumericalAxis secondaryAxis = new SFNumericalAxis();
        chart.SecondaryAxis = secondaryAxis;

        SFLineSeries series = new SFLineSeries()
        {
            XBindingPath = "timestamp",

            YBindingPath = "price_btc",

            ListenPropertyChange = true
        };
        series.EnableTooltip = true;
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        set.Bind(series).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.CoinHistory);
        set.Apply();
```

viewModel(init):

```
CoinHistory = new ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel>(_CoinHistoryGraph.Select(x => new ChartDataModel(float.Parse(x.price_btc), x.timestamp)));
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CoinHistory);
```

ViewModel properties:

```
  private ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel> _CoinHistory;
    public ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel> CoinHistory
    {
        get
        {
            return _CoinHistory;
        }
        set
        {
            _CoinHistory = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CoinHistory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you call `CoinHistory = new ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel>(_CoinHistoryGraph.Select(x => new ChartDataModel(float.Parse(x.price_btc), x.timestamp)));` , If possible could you provide sample for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT i added the viewModel properties, on Init it get the data from an api, and write them in the ObservableCollection.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT this is an example how it is setup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138855/syncfusion-chart-does-not-display-data

Comment: I checked the sample , it create CoinHistory with every clicking event, i think you should call the code `CoinHistory = new ObservableCollection<ChartDataModel>(_CoinHistoryGraph.Select(x => new ChartDataModel(float.Parse(x.price_btc), x.timestamp)));` when  you are choosing the tableview item.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT that does not change anything since its awiated

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT also, i have 2 different views, diffirent data, graph stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you pass your model data to the details view? According to your descriptions, the first ViewModel should hold the whole data. When user click one cell, the tableView source's `SelectionChangedCommand` event will trigger. Normally we bind this command to the corresponding ViewModel's command, then we can configure the push and pass the parameters there.

Here is my bind in the first view which contains a `UITableView`:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel>();

set.Bind(source).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.ItemsGroup);
set.Bind(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.ShowDetailsCommand);

set.Apply();
```

When user click one cell in the TableView, `ShowDetailsCommand` will fire in the `FirstViewModel`:

```
private readonly Lazy<IMvxNavigationService> _navigationService = new Lazy<IMvxNavigationService>(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>);

private MvxCommand<Item> showDetailsCommand;
public ICommand ShowDetailsCommand
{
    get
    {
        return showDetailsCommand ?? (showDetailsCommand = new MvxCommand<Item>(showDetails));
    }
}
async void showDetails(Item item)
{
    // This item is bound to the ItemsSource through ItemsGroup
    await _navigationService.Value.Navigate<SecondViewModel, Item>(item);
}
```

Then the second ViewModel can accept this item via:

```
public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel<Item>
{
    private List<CoinHistoryModel> _CoinHistory;

    public List<CoinHistoryModel> CoinHistory
    {
        get
        {
            return _CoinHistory;
        }
        set
        {
            _CoinHistory = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CoinHistory);
        }
    }

    public override void Prepare(Item parameter)
    {
        CoinHistory = parameter.SingleCoinHistory;
    }
}
```

At last the details view will show the `CoinHistory`, if you have successfully bound it to the second view model.

[Here](https://github.com/landl0526/SFChartUsingMVVMCrossDemo) is my demo for you referring to.

Comment: yes, i have similar code, but since it is not related to the issue I didn't post it.

Comment: Have you checked my sample? I have different cells showing different graph data.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate the issue you have stated here, instead I have prepared a sample based on your requirement and you can find the sample from the below link.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/208547/ze/IOS_MasterDetailPage-2050401038)

If this does not resolve your query, can you revert me back with more details.

Hope this helps

Note: I work for Syncfusion.